# Automapper 8 does not map two entities with same properties without config

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, automapper, aspnetboilerplate

Previously, in version 7, i have written lots of mapping from inputdto to entity without config, but in version 8 i have to write empty config for these types of mappings, how can i avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In asp.net boilerplate, you can use the AutoMap Attribute to define mappings without having to write the configurations explicitly.

```
[AutoMap(typeof(User))]
public class UserDto
```

[Here is the reference to it](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Object-To-Object-Mapping#auto-mapping-attributes)